# Adding an image to a pdf via pdfbox but after adding the pdf get blank

Tags: java, pdfbox

```java
 import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;  
 import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;  
 import java.io.File;  
 import java.io.IOException;  
 import java.util.Scanner;  
 import javax.imageio.ImageIO;  
 import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.MalformedURLException;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument; 
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage; 
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream; 
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;

 public class One {
      /**  
       * @param args  
       */  
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
           Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);  
           System.out.println("Enter base64 string to be converted to image");  
           String base64=s.nextLine();  
           byte[] base64Val=convertToImg(base64);
           writeByteToImageFile(base64Val, "image.png");
           System.out.println("Saved the base64 as image in current directory with name image.png");
           addImageToPDF();
      }
      public static byte[] convertToImg(String base64) throws IOException  
      {  
           return Base64.decodeBase64(base64);  
      }  
      public static void writeByteToImageFile(byte[] imgBytes, String imgFileName) throws IOException  
      {  
           File imgFile = new File(imgFileName);
           BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgBytes));
           ImageIO.write(img, "png", imgFile);
      }
      
      public static void addImageToPDF() throws IOException {
          File file = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\Risk Template(RiskTemplate).pdf"); 
          PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);  
          PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);
          PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("D:\\Development\\Workspace\\1\\image.png", doc); 
          PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
          contents.drawImage(pdImage, 5, 5);     
          System.out.println("Image inserted");  
          contents.close();       
          doc.save("D:\\Development\\Workspace\\1\\InsertImage_OP.pdf"); 

          doc.close();
      }
 }
```

I am creating an image from base64 string and then trying to attach that image to a pdf. The image is creating successfully and the image is being added to the pdf as well but the pdf (output) contains just the image at a corner and the content of the original pdf is now blank.

Comment: Use a different `PDPageContentStream`. See the JavaDoc documentation of that class for details.

Comment: I see `com.itextpdf` imports but I don't see you using anything of the iText API. Can the `itext` tag be removed from this question?

Comment: use PDPageContentStream(document, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true); . Your current code should have given you a warning "You are overwriting an existing content, you should use the append mode". If you didn't get the warning then you have disabled log messages, or haven't been shown them, or didn't look at them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As MKL & Tilman have written in their comment you have to use

`PDPageContentStream(document, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);`

```
public static void addImageToPDF() throws IOException {
          File file = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\Risk Template(RiskTemplate).pdf"); 
          PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);  
          PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);
          PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("D:\\Development\\Workspace\\1\\image.png", doc); 
          PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
          contents.drawImage(pdImage, 5, 5);     
          System.out.println("Image inserted");  
          contents.close();       
          doc.save("D:\\Development\\Workspace\\1\\InsertImage_OP.pdf"); 

          doc.close();
      }
```

Disclaimer: This answer was given by MKL/Tilman but for further reference an answer is more "visible" than a comment.

Comment: Well, I was too lazy to make it an actual answer, so there's a +1 here for you...